# TestNG enabled = false tests not showing as Skipped

Tags: testing, testng

We have a number of TestNG tests that are disabled due to functionality not yet being present (enabled = false), but when the test classes are executed the disabled tests do not show up as skipped in the TestNG report. We'd like to know at the time of execution how many tests are disabled (i.e. skipped). At the moment we have to count the occurrences of enabled = false in the test classes which is an overhead.

Is there a different annotation to use or something else we are missing so that our test reports can display the number of disabled tests?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML reports don't support disabled tests but the Eclipse plug-in view does.

If you really want to see these tests as skipped, you can re-enable them and throw a SkipException() in them.

Comment: SkipException() will cause a Maven build to fail, so it is not equivalent to enabled = false. Also, my version of Eclipse plug-in view does not show enabled = false as skipped - Eclipse indigo with TestNG plugin 6.8.6.20130607_0745